# Using O365 Javascript People Picker authentication

Tags: javascript, office365, peoplepicker

I am running into an authentication issue while trying to implement the [example outlined here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/javascript-controls#create-the-people-picker-control).

My Azure app settings have been modified as outlined in the example but I'm missing something somewhere.

My asp.net app authenticates the user server-side (no problems there) but I'd like to use the result of the authentication as the basis for the people-picker authentication if possible (The above listed example attempts to authenticate during the page's `onload` event).

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var implicitGrantLogin = createLoginProvider();
    createAppChrome(implicitGrantLogin);

    var authContext = implicitGrantLogin.getAuthContext();

    showPeoplePicker(authContext);
};

function createLoginProvider() {
    var config = {
        clientId: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", //my app clientID masked
        redirectUri: 'https://localhost:44343/Account/signin-oidc',
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location,
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage' // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
    };

    var loginProvider = new Office.Controls.ImplicitGrantLogin(config);

    return loginProvider;
}

function createAppChrome(loginProvider) {
    var ItemtoAdd = {
        "Customized Item 1": "http://www.contoso.com/item1", // put your customized item 1 page
        "Customized Item 2": "http://www.contoso.com/item2", // put your customized item 2 page
        "Customized Item 3": "http://www.contoso.com/item3" // put your customized item 3 page
    };
    options = new Object();
    options.appHomeUrl = "https://localhost:44343/Account/signin-oidc"; // put your home page url
    options.customizedItems = ItemtoAdd;
    var appChrome =
        new Office.Controls.AppChrome("Contoso App", document.getElementById('container'), loginProvider, options);
}
```

Exception details

```
System.Exception: Correlation failed.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.<HandleRequestAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? I'm not clear what issue you ran into.

Comment: Marc - yes there is an error and I've added the exception details to my original post. The error is received after attempting to login by clicking the login button in the AppChrome control which redirects to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?... I select my account and then the error is generated. Please let me know what additional info you might need.

Comment: Where are you seeing this error surface?

Comment: I've made some progress - I am able to login successfully and populate a list of users in the people picker control. The oauth2AllowImplicitFlow attribute in my applications manifest (in the Azure app portal) had been flipped back to False inadvertently. Once set back to True everything worked as expected.

Comment: Now that I'm past the first hurdle, I'd like to use the people picker control within an ASP.NET/Angular app. The first thing I do when this app is launched is to authenticate the user server-side so that later some Graph queries can be run. Is it possible to share the authContext established at launch with the people picker and if so how?